How to count from two tables that have a common field, but sometimes there are no matching records on one of them
let me explain what im trying to achieve (im using Bigquery):
I have two tables, one called requests and another one called incidents, in the requests table there are records by application that save every request with its status code 200, 500, 404, etc. In the incidents table there are also records of incidents by each application.
I need to make a report that has each application name, and then count the number of 200 request, count the number of any request that was not 200 and finally the number of incidents of each application.
I managed to make a query that works but there is a "rare" scenario where there can be incidents for an application, but no records at the request table (no 200 requests, no 500 requests, nothing), so in that case my query does not return the incident count since it could not find records at the requests table for that same application. I need help to still show that particular application name, with the count of requests on 0 and the incident count correctly, but have not been able to achieve this, here is my query:
SELECT
  directoryName AS directoryProviderId, -- this is the app name
  COUNTIF(operationStatus = 200) AS successfulOps,
  COUNTIF(operationStatus <> 200) AS failedOps,
  (
    SELECT
      COUNT(*) AS incidentCount
    FROM
      `incidents` i
    WHERE
      r.directoryName=i.directoryProviderId
      -- Only get incidents from yesterday (starts from yesterday at 00:00 until yesterday at 23:59 Lima time)
      AND DATETIME(TIMESTAMP_MILLIS(i.timestamp), "America/Lima") >= DATE_SUB(CURRENT_DATE('America/Lima'), INTERVAL 1 DAY)
      AND DATETIME(TIMESTAMP_MILLIS(i.timestamp), "America/Lima") < CURRENT_DATE('America/Lima')
  ) AS incidents
FROM
  `requests` AS r
WHERE
  -- Only get requests from yesterday (starts from yesterday at 00:00 until yesterday at 23:59 Lima time)
  DATETIME(TIMESTAMP_MILLIS(r.timestamp), "America/Lima") >= DATE_SUB(CURRENT_DATE('America/Lima'), INTERVAL 1 DAY)
  AND DATETIME(TIMESTAMP_MILLIS(r.timestamp), "America/Lima") < CURRENT_DATE('America/Lima')
GROUP BY
  directoryName

The requests table has the following columns:
requestId (String), operationStatus (Integer), timestamp (Integer), directoryName (String)
The incidents table has the following columns:
incidentId (String), directoryProviderId (String), timestamp (Integer)

What if no incidents and no requests? Do you want row (App,0,0,0)?

@ValNik Sure, I first though that if there are no req and also no incidents, the query would not include that appname anyways, but if it does, it would not make any harm to see it 0 0 0

If event logs is written to separate tables, you can count events for every tables and join subqueries outputs on common column(s).
If INNER JOIN used, result output include only event counts, presented in all subqueries (tables).
If LEFT JOIN used, result output include all event counts from LEFT table, and relevant counts from other.
If FULL JOIN used, result output include all event counts from all tables.
There null values necessary convert to 0.
You can count events separately for requests and incidents tables. Then join and take not null values. Use FULL JOIN to get booth side of join.
If you want include all directoryName, join subqueries with table of directory.
See example.
Test data
with requests as 
   (select 'request1' requestId,200 operationStatus
        ,unix_millis(timestamp(cast('2024-04-30 01:00:00' as datetime),'America/Lima'))timestamp
       ,'App1' directoryName
    union all
    select 'request1' requestId,200 operationStatus
        ,unix_millis(timestamp(cast('2024-04-30 02:00:00' as datetime),'America/Lima'))timestamp
        ,'App2' directoryName
   )
,incidents 
   as(
      select 'fail1'incidentId,'App1' directoryProviderId
     ,unix_millis(timestamp(cast('2024-04-30 01:00:00' as datetime)
     ,'America/Lima'))timestamp
   union all
      select 'fail1'incidentId,'App3' directoryProviderId,unix_millis(timestamp(cast('2024-04-30 01:00:00' as datetime),'America/Lima'))timestamp
   )

Query
   select coalesce(i.directoryProviderId,r.directoryProviderId) as directoryProviderId
     ,coalesce(r.successfulOps,0) as successfulOps
     ,coalesce(r.failedOps,0) as failedOps
     ,coalesce(i.incidentCount,0) as incidentCount
   from(
     SELECT
        directoryName AS directoryProviderId, -- this is the app name
        COUNTIF(operationStatus = 200) AS successfulOps,
        COUNTIF(operationStatus <> 200) AS failedOps,
     FROM `requests` AS r
     WHERE
  -- Only get requests from yesterday (starts from yesterday at 00:00 until yesterday at 23:59 Lima time)
        DATETIME(TIMESTAMP_MILLIS(r.timestamp), "America/Lima") >= DATE_SUB(CURRENT_DATE('America/Lima'), INTERVAL 1 DAY)
     AND DATETIME(TIMESTAMP_MILLIS(r.timestamp), "America/Lima") < CURRENT_DATE('America/Lima')
     GROUP BY   directoryName
   ) as r
   full  join 
     (
     SELECT directoryProviderId,
       COUNT(*) AS incidentCount
     FROM `incidents` i
     WHERE
      -- Only get incidents from yesterday (starts from yesterday at 00:00 until yesterday at 23:59 Lima time)
       DATETIME(TIMESTAMP_MILLIS(i.timestamp), "America/Lima") >= DATE_SUB(CURRENT_DATE('America/Lima'), INTERVAL 1 DAY)
       AND DATETIME(TIMESTAMP_MILLIS(i.timestamp), "America/Lima") < CURRENT_DATE('America/Lima')
     group by directoryProviderId
   ) as i
      on i.directoryProviderId= r.directoryProviderId




Row
directoryProviderId
successfulOps
failedOps
incidentCount




1
App1
1
0
1


2
App2
1
0
0


3
App3
0
0
1




Works as expected, thanks mate, im only wondering why did you ask me about the scenario where no records on both tables are found (no requests and no incidents for an app), this scenario just does not show any app name or any counts (no row on the result and this is correct I believe hehe)

Suppose we need to answer the question: Do we have applications that have not registered activity this month? (App,0,0,0)

I see, yeah that could be another report, then we could use this same query but just add a WHERE clause, for succesfulOps = 0, failedOps = 0... right? But I think then it could be tricky, because we cannot get app names from nowere, then we would need another table to fetch the app names from (like a 3rd table called applications to get all app names and then apply this query(?))

Yes, there need another table to fetch the app names.
